# Best deployment method for IIS

Tags: git, iis, deployment

i have a dedicated server running windows server 2012, and i'm not very familiar whit iis, and i want to get a way to have my web site on a git repository and make deployment to the iss server, but i really dont know the best/correct way to do it can somebody point me in the right direction ?

Comment: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu - posted it here to as it does exactly what you want

Answer (score 2):

In the end, deploying a web application generally involves copying the files to a location on the server that the site is to be served from, so its really a rather simple process.

Don't try to tie your source control instance to your deployment directly. instead use your development environment to provide any additional assistance you need during deployment. Continuous integration is great for testing and development, but don't turn it into continuous deployment. GIT is a great tool, but its not specific to any particular executing environment, and it would be unreasonable to expect it to be able to perform deployment ops to all the different kinds of httpds and database platforms.

so, initially, build your IIS site, and configure it as needed. I'd recommend using virtual directories, instead of serving the site directly from inetpub\www\. that allows you to preserve older versions, and to quickly change between them as needed.

then when you deploy, copy your code up to the server (I usually put mine in a folder with the TFS changset number, so you'd use some GIT generation number instead) and once copy is complete, just point the virtual directory to the new version of the app.

Comment: huuumm but i wnat an automated way of doing it because right now im using ftp but it keep giving me errors because some files are being used in the moment that i'm coping them

Comment: i want to get rid of that problem and automate the operation(i work with designers and i want to make it easier)

Comment: Sorry, app deployment should never ever ever be so easy you don't need to think about it. thats how servers get rooted.

Comment: Checkout kudu - it does exactly what you want: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu